# Common Tags For Issues

Tags: project-management, tags

I have been using Issue Tracking system for a week . Right now , I do not really know How to categorize my tickets.I mostly use "enhancement" and "bug" tags .However I want to be more specific about tags.On google's project hosting page I saw tags like "UI" etc,but generally my tickets include lots of part of my application, so I can not use "ui" or "logic". Therefore, I want to learn **Which tags do you use to categorize your tickets?**. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Defect - obvious
- Change Request - something a client has requested which we'll charge for
- Tweak - a change request which is so small it's faster to do it than write up the client documentation and do the estimate
- Enhancement - suggestions for improvements that are unlikely to be funded by a client but may be worth doing (usually raised internally rather than by clients)
- Support - general operational support type questions - how do I do this type stuff
- Documentation - change needed to product documentation

The other on I've used in the past is configuration - where the issue can be resolved by changing application configuration.  We use Bugzilla and this is a resolution type in our current set up rather than an issue type but depending on the nature of your product you may want it set up differently.

I'd stick to 5 - 8 maximum.  Beyond that things get confusing and misclassified so it's not really worth it.

Beyond this we separately classify the area(s) of the application it impacts (a list of about 20, multi-select) which we use for planning regression tests.

As a rule start with less and slowly build up when you feel yourself out growing what's there.